# useEffect not printing div element react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-hooks

I have this Chart component. `useEffect` works as `componentDidMount()` so it should first render the DOM and then should call the `fetchChartData`. But the issue I am facing here is I get `null` in `console.log("111111111", document.getElementById("data-consumed"))` at first and after that I get the DOM elements and resulting I get error from the Highcharts

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Highcharts error #13
```

So I need to know why this is happening as useEffect works as componentDidMount and should render the DOM first.

```
const Chart2 = (props) => {
  const fetchChartData = async () => {
    const { fetchChartData } = props;
    const startDate = moment().startOf("year").toISOString();
    const endDate = moment().endOf("year").toISOString();
    const data = await fetchChartData({ startDate, endDate, userId: "XXXXXXX" });
    console.log("111111111", document.getElementById("data-consumed"))
    Highcharts.chart("data-consumed", {
      chart: {
        type: "column",
      },
      title: {
        text: null,
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: "Source: WorldClimate.com",
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: data.map(({ _id }) => _id),
        crosshair: true,
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: "Rainfall (mm)",
        },
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          pointPadding: -0.1,
          borderWidth: 0,
          color: "#5036D6",
        },
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: null,
          data: data.map(({ processingStorage }) => processingStorage),
        },
      ],
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchChartData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="chart-container cursor-pointer">
      <div className="chart-block">
        <h4>Data Consumed</h4>
        <div id="data-consumed" className="graph-block" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chart2;
```

Comment: @AlanOmar Nopes see the scope for both the functions pls

Comment: Ahh I see it now, have you tried to use `ref` instead of string for the container. that is `Highcharts.chart(ref.current` instead of `Highcharts.chart("data-consumed"` just to see if it make in difference?

Comment: Hi @Profer, I recommend you to use the officially supported wrapper for Highcharts in React: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official However, your code seems to work fine, please check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-fork-w8y1u0?file=/demo.jsx Could you reproduce the problem in codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a setTimeout function. Call the `fetchChartData` function inside `setTimeout`

```
        useEffect(() => {
           setTimeout(()=> {
               fetchChartData();
            }, 2000)
         }, []);
```